# Why does my setCursor() stop on creation of my Tooltips?

Tags: java, javafx, tooltip

Below I set the cursor to be the HAND, however as soon as my Tooltip initiates the hand goes back to the original cursor, until I move and reactivate the hover listener.  Does anyone know why this happens?

```
nodeB.hoverProperty().addListener(l->{
    String[] splittedName = n.getName().split(";");
    String descNames = splittedName[0];
    String officeNames = splittedName[1];
    System.out.println(officeNames);
    Tooltip t = new Tooltip(officeNames);
    nodeB.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
    Tooltip.install(nodeB, t);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you ran into this bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8094371

The card states that this was fixed in 8u20, but by using Windows7 and 8u121 this issue is still present.